# Input type file issue

Tags: html, angularjs

I have simple form it appears when ever i click on edit user
it has input type file, for the first time i edit user input type file is "no file chosen" this is fine bcoz i did select file yet, now i selected a file lets say "Lion.png" and updated, again i clicked on another user edit button, but now input type file is no longer "No file select" it showing me last selected image, it should be "No file selected" right ?? because i did not select any file for this user, why it is showing me last uploaded image automatically

my problem if it is empty i assume that user don't want to edit his picture, i will not change his picture in database, but when it automatically showing Lion.png, it saving Lion.png in the database for this user too, that user don't want, it should be "No file chosen"

i clciked on user 68 for 1st time to edit

[image]

i selected lion.jpg and cicked on save

[image]

now i clicked on user 64 here i only want to change his fist name, observe that file input tag it automatically loading last uploaded file, that i dont want i want it to be empty that is "No file chosen"

[image]

i used AngularJs for this, remember for all this operations page is not reloading is that the problem ??

Comment: Can you please show us some code instead of screenshots? Specifically the piece of code that you have for uploading a file

Comment: After your save function, set the element value null. That should solve it.

Comment: ty, i just used jquery that solved my problem !! :)